# Rotating UIViews become unresponsive

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a UIViewController subclass that changes its frame when the UI rotates (for example, most commonly, the frame is the same size and centered in both landscape and portrait.) When the view rotates, the view visually changes its frame as expected. But the controls (buttons, scroll views, etc.) that end up in the area of the new frame do not respond to touches. The only controls that respond are the ones that have remained in the original frame (so, if the view moves down and to the left, controls or parts of controls in the upper right corner remain responsive.) Any idea what's going on here?

Here's the code that changes the frame:

```
- (void) setLandscape:(bool)bLandscape {

    if( bLandscape )
        [self setFrame:m_landscapeFrame];
    else
        [self setFrame:m_portraitFrame];
}
```

And in the bigger view controller that handles rotation directly:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    bool bToLandscape= UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);

    [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    [m_pCurrentWindowViewController setLandscape:bToLandscape];

    // (Some unrelated stuff happens here...)

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

To me this seems like a bug or at least poor design on Apple's part - there should never be a time when a view is in one position visually and another position in terms of control. But I'm just looking for a way to fix this behavior.

Comment: It seems like the old controls are still associated with the original frame. Because you can't modify `CGRect` directly I don't see any alternative to creating a new frame if you want to change the values. I agree that this seems like poor design. I looked around in the `UIControl` class reference and didn't see any way to associate a control with a new frame. The only thing I can think of is to use the autoresizing features instead of your custom method - if this is possible for your program.

Comment: Definitely use the autosizing springs/struts -- speaking from experience, it's much easier and more reliable than trying to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest workaround I found was to update the frame in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` after animating in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`.